# Parse expression method for JAX-RS

Tags: java, api, parsing, jax-rs, calculator

I need to add JAX-RS  that accepts a string from a client.
this doesn't work when trying from the urls any help would be much appreciated include some examples to help me get my calculator to work thanks

```
@Path("calculate") 
public class Calculator {
long left = 0;
char operator = '+';
Matcher m = SPLIT_REGEX.matcher(expression);
while (m.find()) {
    String operand = "";
    try {
        operand = m.group(1);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        operand = "0";
    }
    left = calculate(left, operator, Long.valueOf(operand));

    String oper = m.group(2);
    if (oper != null)
        operator = oper.charAt(0);

  }
    return left;
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
private long calculate @PathParm(long left, char operator, long right) {
    switch (operator) {
    case '+':
        return left + right;
    case '-':
        return left - right;
    case '*':
        return left * right;
    case '/':
        return left / right;
    case '=':
        return left;
    default:
        return 0L;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? You have 4 Jax rs endpoints already?! What prevents you from creating a 5th method that is annotated with post and that uses your other class?

Comment: Am trying to combine the second class into the first class but not sure how to do it any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Start by clarifying your requirements. What kind of expressions do you want to pass to that rest service? How can the string look like? What is the expected result? And I think you should rather add another endpoint to your second class! And that endpoint instantiates an instance of class one to parse some argument passed to the endpoint!

Comment: above is my attempt with no luck not sure if i have properly incorporated the use oj JAX-RS to work with my client side of the application. any examples of how to correct this ?

Comment: Start by reading [mcve]. What exactly isn't working? As I told you before: what exactly do you intend to do? The above code makes even less sense? And please note: the above wouldnt even compile: you cant just define a class and throw statements into the class body like that. They would need to go inside a method! Sorry, but I think you need a real person (like a tutor or peer) to sit down with you in front of your machine to work through the various aspects that you got wrong. This community has a different scope, we answer specific questions, we aren't a free tutor service.